# networkx: accessing nodes with multiple node attributes via loop

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I have a graph which has nodes/edges. 
I assigned the nodes some attributes

```
 [(1, {'node_rx_signal': 0}),
 (2, {'node_rx_signal': 0}),
 (3, {'node_rx_signal': 1}),
 (4, {'node_rx_signal': 0}),
 (5, {'node_rx_signal': 1}),
 (6, {'node_rx_signal': 0}),
 (7, {'node_rx_signal': 0}),
 (8, {'node_rx_signal': 0})]
```

e.g its is to signify that some nodes have this attribute set to 0 while others don't. 
With the help of for loop with an If condition I want to carry out a task but I can not seem to access the nodes with `'node_rx_signal' == 1`.

```
nx.set_node_attributes(T1,values=0,name='node_rx_signal')
T1.nodes[3]['node_rx_signal'] = 1
T1.nodes[5]['node_rx_signal'] = 1  

for n, data in T1:
    if T1[n][data]==1:
        print(T1.node)
        print([n for n in T1.neighbors(n)])
    else:
        pass
```

Something along these lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines I guess:

```
import networkx as nx

T1 = nx.Graph()
for i in range(1, 9):
    T1.add_node(i)

nx.set_node_attributes(T1, values=0, name='node_rx_signal')
nx.set_node_attributes(T1, values=0, name='node_visited')

T1.nodes[3]['node_rx_signal'] = 1
T1.nodes[5]['node_rx_signal'] = 1
T1.nodes[6]['node_visited'] = 1

for node, attr in T1.nodes(data=True):
    if attr['node_rx_signal'] == 1:
        print(node)
    if attr['node_visited'] == 1:
        print(node)
```

Prints:

```
3
5
6
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. but in case my node has two attributes at the same time e.g [(1, {'node_rx_signal': 0},{'node_visited': 0}), 2.................] 
and can i access the same way but by using 
  if attr['node_visited']==0

Comment: thank you so much for your prompt response.  
I am really grateful!

Answer (score 0):

so your question has already an answer, I really stress out that before posting you should always look by a google search!!
[looping through nodes and extract attributes in Networkx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21627457/looping-through-nodes-and-extract-attributes-in-networkx)

in your case, a for loop calling for the nodes() method will do the trick son't forget the data=True if you are working with the attributes:

```
for my_node in T1.nodes(data=True):
     if my_node["node_rx_signal"] == 1:
          print(my_node)
```

Comment: The syntax is wrong. `G.nodes(data=True)` returns a tuple.

Comment: I had tried this earlier but the error was the same

Comment: what version of networkx are you using? Could you provide an example networks?